# Seamless login between an MVC/Core application and a Web Forms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, hash

I am currently developing a Web Forms application to work with my company's MVC/.NET Core application. I see that there is an ApplicationNameAuth database that has tables like AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers, etc.

In the AspNetUsers table there are fields like Username and PasswordHash. I would like to enable my application to use the same login scheme so that we don't have to set up a new set of usernames and password for everyone to remember. How is the password hashed to get the PasswordHash result? I can set up my own login page and use the emails from that table as login names, and if I can hash the entered password to make sure it matches the one in that table, it will work great. The only thing is, I don't know the method that was used to get that hash. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to Identity, the passwords are hashed using PBKDF2. Whether WebForms can verify the version used in Core, I don't know, given the source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs - the last version of WebForms I worked with used the Crypto class, which only has a version 0 PBKDF2 implementation (if my memory is correct). You could always try porting the linked code to .NET Framework, using you're using a version with the necessary crypto updates.

Comment: Up front, I will say that I know almost nothing about cryptography. From this page, it says at minimum I will need a password and a salt to derive the key(I assume this means the PasswordHash?). So, if I wanted to make my own page that hashes these passwords in the same way to check them against that database table, I would have the user enter his or her password, but what do I use as the salt?

Comment: If you wind up adapting the linked code, you don't  need to derive the salt - it's part of the value that's stored in the Password field in the database. You would just use the VerifyPassword method.